# Docusign Recipient Status - What does Passed status mean? Is that the same as Completed?

Tags: docusignapi

We send documents to Docusign for signature (from our application) and then we poll for Completed status to download the documents back once the clients sign them.

But recently we allowed Clients to use ID Lookup feature for Authentication. While polling we could see Passed status instead of the usual Completed status. This is after the Clients successfully authenticate themselves and sign the document.

When does this Passed status come into play? Can we treat them as equivalent to Completed?

Answer (score 2):

"*Passed*" is neither an Envelope-level status nor a Recipient-level status.  Rather, in the case of *ID Check* authentication, it's a status value that corresponds to either **idLookupResult** or **idQuestionResult** within the **recipientAuthenticationStatus** property of the "Get Recipients" API response.  For example, here's the "Get Recipients" request/response for an completed envelope where the recepient successfully passed ID Check authentication:

```
GET https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/ENVELOPE_ID/recipients?include_tabs=false&include_extended=true

{
    "signers": [
        {
            "signInEachLocation": "false",
            "name": "Jane Doe",
            "email": "janesemail@outlook.com",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "recipientIdGuid": "bee5eae6-3e7a-4692-8488-0bf331a817b6",
            "requireIdLookup": "true",
            "idCheckConfigurationName": "ID Check $",
            "userId": "3a8ce8f4-fe2c-479f-bc44-2502cc8d0558",
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "note": "",
            "status": "completed",
            "signedDateTime": "2014-08-14T18:12:50.0530000Z",
            "deliveredDateTime": "2014-08-14T18:09:59.3700000Z",
            "recipientAuthenticationStatus": {
                "idLookupResult": {
                    "status": "Passed",
                    "eventTimestamp": "2014-08-14T18:08:55.6430000Z"
                },
                "idQuestionsResult": {
                    "status": "Passed",
                    "eventTimestamp": "2014-08-14T18:08:55.6430000Z"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "agents": [],
    "editors": [],
    "intermediaries": [],
    "carbonCopies": [],
    "certifiedDeliveries": [],
    "inPersonSigners": [],
    "recipientCount": "1",
    "currentRoutingOrder": "1"
}
```

(Notice that the Recipient's **status** is *completed*.)

If you're interested in retrieving documents once an Envelope is complete, then you should be focused solely upon evaluating ***Envelope*** status -- if the Envelope status is "***completed***, then that means all recipients have submitted the Envelope (i.e., completed their required actions).  The following "Get Envelope Status" request/response shows an example for a "completed" Envelope (i.e., **status** = *completed*).

```
GET https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/ENVELOPE_ID

{
    "status": "completed",
    "documentsUri": "/envelopes/71bcc905-916d-4253-ba4c-7e6d6de519ec/documents",
    "recipientsUri": "/envelopes/71bcc905-916d-4253-ba4c-7e6d6de519ec/recipients",
    "envelopeUri": "/envelopes/71bcc905-916d-4253-ba4c-7e6d6de519ec",
    "emailSubject": "Test w/ ID Check",
    "emailBlurb": "Test Email Body",
    "envelopeId": "71bcc905-916d-4253-ba4c-7e6d6de519ec",
    "customFieldsUri": "/envelopes/71bcc905-916d-4253-ba4c-7e6d6de519ec/custom_fields",
    "notificationUri": "/envelopes/71bcc905-916d-4253-ba4c-7e6d6de519ec/notification",
    "enableWetSign": "false",
    "allowReassign": "false",
    "createdDateTime": "2014-08-14T18:04:34.0900000Z",
    "deliveredDateTime": "2014-08-14T18:09:59.4030000Z",
    "sentDateTime": "2014-08-14T18:05:57.1300000Z",
    "completedDateTime": "2014-08-14T18:12:50.0700000Z",
    "statusChangedDateTime": "2014-08-14T18:12:50.0700000Z",
    "documentsCombinedUri": "/envelopes/71bcc905-916d-4253-ba4c-7e6d6de519ec/documents/combined",
    "certificateUri": "/envelopes/71bcc905-916d-4253-ba4c-7e6d6de519ec/documents/certificate",
    "templatesUri": "/envelopes/71bcc905-916d-4253-ba4c-7e6d6de519ec/templates",
    "purgeState": "unpurged"
}
```